# How to disable contextIsolation and enable nodeIntegration for cypress electron tests?

Tags: electron, cypress

I am trying to access these properties (made available by [this](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/pull/15493) update).

I tried the following in `cypress.config.ts` but it does not seem to be working:

```
export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
      on("before:browser:launch", (browser, launchOptions) => {
        launchOptions.preferences.webPreferences.contextIsolation = false;
        launchOptions.preferences.webPreferences.nodeIntegration = true;
      });
    },
  },
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a browser check as launch options are specific to Electron and will stop other browsers running. Then return the launch options.

```js
export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('before:browser:launch', (browser = {}, launchOptions) => {
        if (browser.name === 'electron') {
          launchOptions.preferences.webPreferences.nodeIntegration = true;
          launchOptions.preferences.webPreferences.contextIsolation = false;
          launchOptions.preferences.webPreferences.enableRemoteModule = true;
        }
        return launchOptions;
      })
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must return the launchOptions object in your callaback for them to take effect.

https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/browser-launch-api#Modify-browser-launch-arguments-preferences-extensions-and-environment

```js
export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
      on("before:browser:launch", (browser, launchOptions) => {
        launchOptions.preferences.webPreferences.contextIsolation = false;
        launchOptions.preferences.webPreferences.nodeIntegration = true;
        return launchOptions;
      });
    },
  },
});
```